# How do I use media queries with SASS?

Tags: sass, media-queries

How do I 'open the media query code block' so I can start defining my styles?

Google was unhelpful (was all about scss rather than SASS - the layout isn't the same I don't think)

Comment: If you're starting out with Sass, beware that most of the so called Sass wrote now uses Scss syntax. For example, old Sass syntax does not use braces nor semi-colons. New Sass syntax (SCSS) does. Are you actually using the old `.sass` extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the SASS docs, instead of SCSS, I would look at the `SASS_REFERENCE` file from an old (pre-3.x) version of the Sass gem.

Looking at the [`doc-src/SASS_REFERENCE` file](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/2.2.24/doc-src/SASS_REFERENCE.md) from the 2.2.24 tag in the official [Sass Github repo](https://github.com/nex3/sass), I found this reference for `@media` queries:

```
@media print
  #sidebar
    display: none

  #main
    background-color: white
```

compiles to:

```css
@media print {
  #sidebar {
    display: none; }

  #main {
    background-color: white; } }
```

See the rest of the [reference file](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/2.2.24/doc-src/SASS_REFERENCE.md) for details.

Comment: But of course, I would also recommend upgrading to SCSS instead of the older SASS syntax, since it will be supported going forward and is generally easier to use.

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, its a shame that most people use scss now rather than the old version. I prefer its lack of curly braces, and semincolons. Although it completely breaks if you add one by accident :( I think i at start using stylus instead. http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/